# Cast data during conditional postgres selection

Tags: postgresql

I have long table format data which has all data stored as text type. I don't have permissions to add functions on the db etc. Pg version 12+. I have many rows i need to create and cast to numeric, as below first attempt.

```sql
SELECT t1.sid as record_number
, (MAX((t1.data)::numeric) FILTER ( WHERE t1.cid = 112)) AS new_field1_numeric
, (MAX((t1.data)::numeric) FILTER ( WHERE t1.cid = 122))  AS new_field2_numeric
FROM original_data t1 
WHERE t1.nid = 10090
GROUP BY t1.sid
```

This returns the error `invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` as the data is stored text with unused fields having no content.

What I've tried:

```sql
(MAX((t1.data)::numeric) FILTER ( WHERE (t1.cid = 122) and (t1.data != '') ))  AS new_field2_numeric
```

which returns same error

and

```sql
(MAX (CASE WHEN ((t1.cid=122)) then ((regexp_replace(t1.data, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric) else 0::numeric end) ) as test_numeric
```

which returns `ERROR: cannot cast type record to numeric`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, where field will be latter summed and only postive numeric values are possible, the answer was

```sql
(MAX(CASE
WHEN t1.cid = 122 AND t1.data != '' THEN t1.data::numeric
ELSE 0::numeric 
END))AS field2_numeric
```

if null values were possible this becomes

```sql
(MAX(CASE
WHEN t1.cid = 122 AND t1.data ISNULL THEN NULL
WHEN t1.cid = 122 AND t1.data != '' THEN t1.data::numeric
ELSE 0::numeric 
END))AS field2_numeric
```